# Emulator closing after some time and showing error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using ubuntu 14.04(32 bit) and installed all necessary things for android development environment. When I am launching emulator than It will open and than close after some time and showing error:

> emulator-arm: .//tcg/optimize.c:158: tcg_opt_gen_mov: Assertion
>   `temps[src].state != TCG_TEMP_CONST' failed.

In addition, I added emulator command line option field

> -force-32bit

but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your Target platform number from Project-> Properties-> Android.

2) Then Go to your AVD manager from Windows -> AVD manager, Check whether there is any AVD that matches the API level and Platform of the Target obtained in 1).

If no such AVD is present, create new with the same platform and API level as 1).